# Hash Tables: Ransom Note - Hackerrank Java List Implementaion

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to implement list to solve this Hackerrank problem but 9/22 case getting failed. I am not sure what is the proble.
Here is the link to that problem::: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps

```
        List a = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(magazine)); 
        List b = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(note));
        a.retainAll(b);
        if(a.equals(b)) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }         
}
```

Comment: You should paste the tasks description directly in the question and not reuqire us to visit some other sites to be able to answer your question.

Comment: In HackerRank, there is already a discussion forum. Please post your issue there you will get correct answer there because there are already experts who help you to solve your issue.

Comment: After looking at the task it seems to me that your problem might be with list ordering. `equals` on a list expects all elements of both lists to be in the same order. From my understanding you code should print "yes" if `a` contains all elements of `b`, order doesn't matter.

Comment: The question says `Hash Tables`, using a `List` is pointless

Comment: Another thing for you to consider is what happens with duplicate elements. I'd guess that you can't reuse the same element twice - your code won't work for this case either.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya I think one could solve the task using Lists but that would probably be quite ineffective.